# for loop inside the append is not working

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jquery-append

below is my code.

```
$("<table/>",{"cellspacing":"0","cellpadding":"0","border":"0","width":"100%"})
.append(
$("<tbody/>")
.append(function(){

    options=["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR"];
    $.each(options, function(val) {
        return ($("<tr/>")
        .append(
            $("<td/>").html("4/6/2013 10:41"),
            $("<td/>").html("5/6/2013 10:42"),
            $("<td/>").html(val),
            $("<td/>").html("<img src='pdf_16x16.png'/>"),
            $("<td/>").html("<a href='#'>Re-Upload Documents</a>")
        ));
    })

})
).appendTo("body");
```

for loop inside the append is not working.

Comment: val is the index here. Is it what you expect? ` $.each(options, function(i,val) {...});` ?

Comment: How does you html look like?

Comment: Typo: you have two closing brackets after the `append`, you need curly brace and a bracket: `});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because you are not returning anything from the `append` function, only the `each` loop within it. Try this:

```
$("<tbody/>").append(function(){
    options = ["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR"];
    var $container = $('<table></table>');

    $.each(options, function(val) {
        $container.append($("<tr/>").append(
            $("<td/>").html("4/6/2013 10:41"),
            $("<td/>").html("5/6/2013 10:42"),
            $("<td/>").html(val),
            $("<td/>").html("<img src='pdf_16x16.png'/>"),
            $("<td/>").html("<a href='#'>Re-Upload Documents</a>")
        ));
    });

    return $container.html();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MHdGM/)

Comment: Thanks. it is working. but it should be tr not div in container variable. great!.

Comment: @Natesan Why? He is returning the content not the element. Maybe he could use a TABLE but not a TR

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var tbody = $("<tbody/>").appendTo($("<table/>", {
    "cellspacing" : "0",
    "cellpadding" : "0",
    "border" : "0",
    "width" : "100%"
}).appendTo("body"));

options = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"];
$.each(options, function(key, val) {
    return tbody
    .append($("<tr/>")
            .append($("<td/>").html("4/6/2013 10:41"))
            .append($("<td/>").html("5/6/2013 10:42"))
            .append($("<td/>").html(val))
            .append($("<td/>").html("<img src='pdf_16x16.png'/>"))
            .append($("<td/>").html("<a href='#'>Re-Upload Documents</a>")));
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9mDkR/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$.each(options, function(val) {
    return ($("<tr/>")
    .append(
        $("<td/>").html("4/6/2013 10:41") + 
        $("<td/>").html("5/6/2013 10:42") +
        $("<td/>").html(val) +
        $("<td/>").html("<img src='pdf_16x16.png'/>") +
        $("<td/>").html("<a href='#'>Re-Upload Documents</a>")
    ));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
$("<table/>",{"cellspacing":"0","cellpadding":"0","border":"0","width":"100%"})
.append("<tbody></tbody>").appendTo("body");

$("tbody").append(function(){
  options = ["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR"];
   var $container = $('<div></div>');

$.each(options, function(val) {
    $container.append($("<tr/>").append(
        $("<td/>").html("4/6/2013 10:41"),
        $("<td/>").html("5/6/2013 10:42"),
        $("<td/>").html(val),
        $("<td/>").html("<img src='pdf_16x16.png'/>"),
        $("<td/>").html("<a href='#'>Re-Upload Documents</a>")
    ));
});

  return $container.html();
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mCLsm/2/