# Uncaught TypeError: elem.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here what i'm trying to do : 
[for loop inside the append is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101099/for-loop-inside-the-append-is-not-working)

Here my code :

```
$('body').append(
    $('<section>').append(
        $('<form>')
        .attr('class', "ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-cross")
        .attr('autocomplete', "off")
        .append(
            $('<h2>')
            .html(
                "Your to do list to uniquely deploy cross-unit s:"
            ),

            function() {
                options = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"];
                var $container = $('<ol></ol>');
                $.each(options, function(val) {
                    $container.append($('<li>').append(
                        $("<input>").attr('id', "cb" +
                            val)
                        .attr('name', "cb" + val)
                        .attr('type', "checkbox"),
                        $("<label>").attr('for', "cb" +
                            val).append(
                            $('<span>').html(
                                "Quickly incentivize impactful actions"
                            )
                        )
                    ));
                })
                return $('<ol>').html();
            }

        )
    )
)
```

**Error**:

```
jquery-2.1.1.js:5089 Uncaught TypeError: elem.replace is not a function
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the error is triggered by the code you posted? I'd suggest opening developer tools, and configure the debugger to break on uncaught exceptions, you'll be able so see from the stacktrace if it's your code or not the one triggering the error.

Comment: Do you have any documentation you would recommand to perform this operation? Because I never did that.

Comment: `.append(....` What's the second param to `append` doing here? According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/) there is no `.append(DOMString, function)` overload

Comment: Cristik is right. Please provide the correct file.

Comment: @goldiman: Chrome's documentation on developer tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: The problem is you can't mix content and function as arguments to append, if you are passing content alone then you can pass multiple arguments... but if you are passing a function you can use only one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to append both the HTML from your `h2` and the output from the function you pass to `append`, you can just chain the calls:

```
$('body').append(
    $('<section>').append(
        $('<form>')
        .attr('class', "ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-cross")
        .attr('autocomplete', "off")
        .append(
            $('<h2>')
            .html(
                "Your to do list to uniquely deploy cross-unit s:"
            )
        )
        .append(
            function() {
                options = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"];
                var $container = $('<ol></ol>');
                $.each(options, function(val) {
                    $container.append($('<li>').append(
                        $("<input>").attr('id', "cb" +
                            val)
                        .attr('name', "cb" + val)
                        .attr('type', "checkbox"),
                        $("<label>").attr('for', "cb" +
                            val).append(
                            $('<span>').html(
                                "Quickly incentivize impactful actions"
                            )
                        )
                    ));
                })
                return $container.html();
            }

        )
    )
)
```

But no wonder you're having trouble seeing the problem. You should split this out into smaller, more manageable parts

Comment: Thank you, your code solve one part of the problem, now I do have the h2 display but not the output of the function.

Comment: You just have to change `return $('<ol>').html();` with `return $container.html();`